# default model manager only get objects that belong to a logged in user

Tags: django, django-models, django-managers

When I get a list of objects I only ever want to the objects that belong to the logged in user.

I'm thinking, maybe this can be done in the model manager by overriding the default manager, but I'm unsure how to get the logged in use. This is what I have so far...

```
class GroupsManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(GroupsManager, self).get_query_set().filter(user=???????)
```

I'm I on the right track? How can I achieve my goal? Or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have access to the `request` (and therefore the currently logged in user) in the model or model manager. So you could write a generic manager method that accepts a user instance and only returns objects belonging to that user:

```
class GroupsManager(models.Manager):
    def for_user(self, user):
        return self.get_query_set().filter(user=user)
```

and in your model:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    objects = GroupsManager()
```

and in the view:

```
def my_view(request):
    groups = Group.objects.for_user(request.user)
```

Comment: why don't you need 'super' here?

Comment: where abouts? On `self.get_query_set`? That's because I'm not overwriting the `get_query_set` method, I'm creating my own method that accepts a parameter instead and making use of the default `get_query_set` method (so therefore there is no need to call the parent)

Comment: For current Django (1.9), this must be `get_queryset()`, not `get_query_set()`.  I believe this is true since version 1.6.

Comment: I get error message "'PortfolioManager' object has no attribute 'get_query_set'". I use the get_queryset() idea above but not getting the filtered objects based on user.